# Atomic actions with ZooKeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

How to gather number of action in ZooKeeper into one atomic action with one result (pass/fails)?

I read that ZooKeeper supports this with "multiop", but I haven't found it on version 3.4.6. 
(was MultiCallback name changed?)

Comment: multiop support was not added until the 3.5.0 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zookeeper transactions. [Apache Curator library](http://curator.apache.org/) for ZooKeeper provide nice syntax.

For example, to modify several nodes in a transaction:

```
client.inTransaction().
.setData().forNode(path1, data1)
.and()
.SetData().forNode(path2, data2)
.and()
.commit();
```